# Laravel 5.4 Maatwebsite Excel working on local but not live server

Tags: laravel-5.4, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Maatwebsite to handle excel creation on my Laravel app. I built it on my local and it works fine. I essentially create the first row then make a xls sheet and export it. I don't store it anywhere. When you click the create template button the route goes to a controller that creates it but basically it doesn't leave the page it just shows the download box, which is the desired result. This works 100% on my local but not on my server. I did everything the same.

I get:
File not found
Firefox can’t find the file at (path/to/controller)

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: your webserver configuration might not configured to download XLS files. whats your webserver ?

Comment: Im running CentoOS7

Comment: nginx or apache ?